# C - Gravação de programa PIC 18F4550 via USB

Tags: c, pic

De início, sou um leigo quando o assunto é programação. Por conta disto, estou desenvolvendo programas rápidos e fáceis, para aprimorar meu conhecimento aos poucos..

Tenho uma placa de desenvolvimento de um PIC18F4550, com LEDS nos pinos RB, alguns no RD e RC. Os botões estão nos pinos de RE.

[image: Placa de desenvolvimento]

Já foi gravado bootloader neste PIC, então estou usando a USB (que está na parte de baixo da placa) para realizar a gravação pelo PC. 
Quando eu gero um código (estou usando o MPLAB X), carrego o .hex no gravador, e ao chegar em 99%, o programa gravador simplesmente pára de responder, e fecha...

[image: Print do programa travado]

Existe algum procedimento que está faltando para a gravação do programa? Detalhe, quando eu gravo um programa feito por um professor da faculdade, ele funciona normalmente. E não consegui encontrar nenhuma parte do programa que altere a configuração de gravação, apenas a lógica de programação mesmo...

Abaixo, está o código que escrevi. O clock que estou utilizando é de 48 MHz, e o oscilador externo é de 20 MHz.

Espero ter sido claro. Um abraço!

```html
#include <xc.h>
#include "config.h"

void configura_uc()
{
    //Configura botão do PORTE como entrada e LEDS como saída
    TRISB=0xFF;
    TRISC=0xFF;
    TRISD=0xFF;
    TRISE=0x00;
}
void main(void) {
    configura_uc();
    while (1)
    {
        if (PORTEbits.RE0 = 1)
        {
            PORTBbits.RB7 = 1;
            PORTBbits.RB6 = 1;
            PORTBbits.RB5 = 1;
            PORTBbits.RB4 = 1;
        }
        if (PORTEbits.RE1 = 1)
        {
            PORTBbits.RB3 = 1;
            PORTBbits.RB2 = 1;
            PORTBbits.RB1 = 1;
            PORTBbits.RB0 = 1;
        }
        if (PORTEbits.RE2 = 1)
        {
            PORTDbits.RD7 = 1;
            PORTDbits.RD6 = 1;
            PORTDbits.RD5 = 1;
            PORTDbits.RD4 = 1;   
        }
    }
    return;
}
```